# node crypto: en/decrypt token for validation

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, token

I want to en- and decrypt a token to be able to determine if it **could be** a valid token without accessing the DB.

My code is working for tokens that look "completely different" but if I only change one letter, a result is returned (no error thrown) thus looking like the token is valid ...!?

This is my code (plus changing the letter manually):

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var cryptSecret = "a!=ksljdk34ajSDkl";
var token = "1d3889647173d415e24195ce5cafc36c1edcc053";

function _encodeUrlSaveBase64(str) {
  return str.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/\=+$/, "");
}

function _decodeUrlSaveBase64(str) {
  str = (str + "===").slice(0, str.length + (str.length % 4));
  return str.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
}

function _encrypt(data) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes256", cryptSecret);
  var str = cipher.update(data, "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");
  str = _encodeUrlSaveBase64(str);
  return str;
}

function _decrypt(data) {
  var str = _decodeUrlSaveBase64(data);
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher("aes256", cryptSecret);
  str = decipher.update(str, "base64", "utf8") + decipher.final("utf8");
  return str;
}

console.log("token:    ", token);
var encrypted = _encrypt(token);
console.log("encrypted:", encrypted);
// change fourth letter to upper-case B (instead of lower-case)
encrypted = "bYzBYnU8FX7Rxs6Hae-yZkXvlwlRnhMQdLrT07e6YBy79nrK8FIpbKbxsYsXUmbk";
console.log("changed  :", encrypted);
console.log("decrypt  :", _decrypt(encrypted));
```

and it outputs:

```
token:     1d3889647173d415e24195ce5cafc36c1edcc053
encrypted: bYzbYnU8FX7Rxs6Hae-yZkXvlwlRnhMQdLrT07e6YBy79nrK8FIpbKbxsYsXUmbk
changed  : bYzBYnU8FX7Rxs6Hae-yZkXvlwlRnhMQdLrT07e6YBy79nrK8FIpbKbxsYsXUmbk
decrypt  : �g�
1З��/b���e2.195ce5cafc36c1edcc053
```

where it should normally throw an error like this:

```
TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:302:27)
    at _decrypt (/***/test.js:25:59)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/***/test.js:35:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1128:3
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is this just the way this works?

Comment: AES in ECB mode does not perform any sort of authentication on the ciphertext. ECB mode is highly dubious anyway since it leaks information about the plaintext and allows for all kinds of interesting replay attacks that involve stitching together several ciphertexts. Cookie encryption is notably very difficult. Also, I hope you didn't share your secret key with the world.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between encryption (hide something) and signing (validate something). In your case you are hiding the content of the token. A simple solution for validating a token is a hash using a secret:

```
hashvalue = tokenvalue + hashfunction(tokenvalue + secret)
```

When validating, cut out the tokenvalue and calculate the hashvalue again, if it does not match someone must have tampered the token. A popular example of this is [LTPA v1](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Third-Party_Authentication).

This scheme has some shortcomings, the biggest would be that every party needs the secret to validate the tokens and is therefore able to create a new valid token. IBM switched to public key for LTPA v2 because of this.

Comment: ok, maybe I misused some of the vocabulary. I "just" want to check if the token *could* be valid. I asked a colleague of mine and he gave me the code above ... if I try to decrypt an invalid token like "aabbcc" the error is thrown and I know that the token is invalid. My problem is that minor changes don't result in an error. In this case I would query the DB and get an error trying to validate it there. Maybe that is the correct behavior?

Comment: If you simply want to know when the token breaks due to transmission errors, use a hash function (like md5, sha1, sha2) without the secret I mentioned. When you want to prevent bad guys from sending malicious / random token, use a hash with a secret. Both is called validation.